# Reading multiple ADCs with STM32F446RET

Tags: c, stm32, sensors, adc, nucleo

i am using the Nucleo64 STM32F446 board and i am trying to read out 3 temperature sensors with the polling method and via DMA but with both methods i can get only 1 correct value. The voltage at every ADC Input is the same. I cannot find the mistake.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here i drop the polling method: (I just followed this Youtube Tut: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5l-b6lsubBE )

```
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

double  Temp1 = 0;
double  Temp2 = 0;
double  Temp3 = 0;

double  resistance1;
double  resistance2;
double  resistance3;




uint16_t ADC_VAL[3];



void ADC_Select_CH1(void){
     ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};
      sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
      sConfig.Rank = 1;
      sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_15CYCLES;
      if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
}


void ADC_Select_CH2(void){
      ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};
      sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_2;
      sConfig.Rank = 1;
      sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_84CYCLES;
      if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
}


void ADC_Select_CH3(void){
    ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};
      sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_3;
      sConfig.Rank = 1;
      sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_112CYCLES;
      if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }

}



/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  uint16_t x =0;
  uint16_t y =0;
  uint16_t z =0;



   /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */

  while (1)
  {




      ADC_Select_CH1();
      HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
      HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 1000);
      ADC_VAL[0] = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
      HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1);

      ADC_Select_CH2();
      HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
      HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 1000);
      ADC_VAL[1] = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
      HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1);

      ADC_Select_CH3();
      HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
      HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 1000);
      ADC_VAL[2] = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
      HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1);

            x = ADC_VAL[0];
            y = ADC_VAL[1];
            z = ADC_VAL[2];

          int resolution = 4096;


         resistance1 =  10000*((x/(double)resolution)/(1-(x/(double)resolution)));
         resistance2 =  10000*((y/(double)resolution)/(1-(y/(double)resolution)));
         resistance3 =  10000*((z/(double)resolution)/(1-(z/(double)resolution)));


          Temp1 = 1/((1/298.15)+((double)1/3435)*log((double)resistance1/10000));
          Temp2 = 1/ ((1/298.15)+((double)1/3435)*log((double)resistance2/10000));
          Temp3 = 1/ ((1/298.15)+((double)1/3435)*log((double)resistance3/10000));


          Temp1 = Temp1 - 273.15;
          Temp2 = Temp2 - 273.15;
          Temp3 = Temp3 - 273.15;



        HAL_Delay(1000);
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 180;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = 2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Activate the Over-Drive mode
  */
  if (HAL_PWREx_EnableOverDrive() != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_5) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief ADC1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 0 */

  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 1 */
  /** Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion)
  */
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV4;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
  hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
//  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
//  */
//  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
//  sConfig.Rank = 1;
//  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_15CYCLES;
//  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
//  {
//    Error_Handler();
//  }
//  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
//  */
//  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_2;
//  sConfig.Rank = 2;
//  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_84CYCLES;
//  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
//  {
//    Error_Handler();
//  }
//  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
//  */
//  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_3;
//  sConfig.Rank = 3;
//  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_112CYCLES;
//  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
//  {
//    Error_Handler();
//  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : B1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_FALLING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(B1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : LD2_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LD2_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LD2_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

Comment: the format don't work if i try to post the hole code

Comment: @Ruffy Just paste the code and while having it marked, click on the `{}` icon for formatting.

Comment: ok with ctl+k it works :)

Comment: *... get only 1 correct value ...* Can you be more specific as to what is going wrong? What do you see happening?

Comment: the Variables Temp1 Temp2 & Temp3 should be nearly the same, it is 3 times the same temperature sensor, i also measured the voltage at the voltage divider connected at the ADC Input and it is every time the same

Comment: What is in `ADC_VAL[]`? Is 21 the expected answer?

Comment: it is just x,y and z, and yes 21 is the correct value

Comment: What exactly does "right alignment" mean? Suppose I get value 0x123 from the ADC, wouldn't that also mean that the `uint16_t` gets the raw binary value `0x0123`. That's wrong for a little endian CPU such as STM32. Even if you'd get `0x0123` that would also be wrong. You want `0x2301`.

Comment: What is the hexadecimal values in ADC_VAL[]?

Comment: Actually i don't know what it means, i tried "left alignment" but its not working

Comment: ADC_VAL[0] = x , ADC_VAL[1] = y ADC_VAL[2]= z

Comment: If you don't do CH1 or CH3 does CH2 have correct value?

Answer (score 0):

i used PA7 and PA4 instead of PA2 & PA3 for the ADC conversion and it's working. It seems that on this Nucleo Board PA2 & PA3 is not suitable for this task.